# e.RowIndex in the parent gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a nested gridview. I have defined gridview_RowDeleting event for the nested gridview.but I have a problem , when I want to delete ,for example,first row in the nested gridview and this nested gridview is in secound or third,..row of parent gridview , I can not delete row in the nested gridview and e.RowIndex for parent gridview is also 0 while it should be 1 or 2,..and for nested gridview it should be 0.

please help how I have to change my code can recognize e.RowIndex for parent gridview is different of e.RowIndex nested gridview.

```
protected void GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{


    GridView TranstoCon = sender as GridView ;
    int transid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewTtransmittals.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(TranstoCon.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    //Also step into this and see what it's doing
    OnDeleteTtransmittaltocon(Id,transid);
```

GridViewTtransmittals is parent gridview and TranstoCon is nested gridview.

```
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are using nested gridview's RowIndex for parent gridview . in this event `e.RowIndex` refers to `nested gridview`'s `current row` not it's parent's . to get parent gridview's current row's index :

```
GridViewRow parentRow = (GridViewRow)TranstoCon.Parent.Parent.Parent;
int parentRowIndex = parentRow.RowIndex;
```

I'm not quite sure either **two** or **three** .Parent is required . you can try both .

so your code could be edited as below :

```
protected void GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e){
GridView TranstoCon = sender as GridView ;

// parent row
var parentRow = (GridViewRow)TranstoCon.Parent.Parent.Parent;

int transid = Convert.ToInt32(parentRow.DataKeys[parentRow.RowIndex].Value);


int Id = Convert.ToInt32(TranstoCon.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

//Also step into this and see what it's doing
OnDeleteTtransmittaltocon(Id,transid);
}
```

you can check this [post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1569299/3930030.aspx)

Comment: just i modified the code :int transid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewTtransmittals.DataKeys[parentRow.RowIndex].Value);
and it is working very good. thanks a lot